# Error while updating property 'X' in shadow node of type: RCTView

Tags: react-native

I have a Item which receives a value from a props value.
This value is not set correctly according to react-native error messaging.

```
export default class BarItem extends Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props);
}

propTypes : {
    color: PropTypes.string,
    barInterval: PropTypes.number,
};
    const {color, barInterval} = this.props;

render () {
    const baseStyle = {
        backgroundColor: color,
        marginRight: barInterval
    };

    return ( <View style={Object.assign({}, baseStyle, {height: (empty * unitHeight)}) } /> );
  }
}
```

I am wondering why I can't update my value , and what a shadow node is, and how to prevent this in the future?

EDIT: something to do with the value of 'barinterval' being a string but only accepting numbers. (wrong value given?)

Comment: what is the `baseStyle` ? can you show?

Comment: nothing to do with `baseStyle` thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: What is that close squared brackets (`]`) for in your return?

Comment: Well noticed, the whole style attribute should be in an array Example:
' style={[Object.assign({}, baseStyle, {height: (empty * unitHeight)]}) } '
without the quotes. because it has multiple styles added to it. No clue if this is still the way to do it now a days , but with React native V0.27 this was the case.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The error explains that it expects a variable as integer, and not as a string value.

**Example**

`<BarItem barInterval={'5'} />` is wrong, but `<BarItem barInterval={5} />` is correct.

In this case the value `marginRight` requires a integer to work, because the variable is used in a stylesheet.

Comment: In my case, it worked oppositely. I passed the number to the style property then an error appeared. Then I changed it to string problem was resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> I was getting below error :

```
error while updating property height in shadow node of type

Reason : I was using style={{height:"20px"}}

Solution: Since I was using Tailwind CSS so I used tailwind class then I got rid of from this error, or else you can use height by creating styleSheet.
```